# How to stop RaspberryPi Terminal Session with SSH command? Like CTRL+C

Tags: android, session, ssh, terminal, raspberry-pi

I want to cancel/stop a running programm on the terminal of my RapsberryPi with a SSH Command. It should have the same effect like press CTRL+C on the keyboard. I control the SSH commands with an Android App.

Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: `kill <program>`

Comment: okay. but if i push the button which sends this command (kill <program>), it will send it after the programm stopped (beacuse it's done).

Comment: `it will send it after the programm stopped` ??? Why would you want to do that? Makes no sense.

Comment: Use a second terminal.

Comment: no i dont wanna do that but it does..